# Thinkpad W540: high power consumption (even when idle)

Tags: nvidia, power-management, battery, thinkpad, powertop

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.4.0-53-generic and i3-wm on my
**Thinkpad W540** 20BH with i7-4600M and Nvidia Quadro K2100

I disabled the discrete GPU via acpi_call to save battery

However the notebook is still consuming around 24 watts on idle (peaks up to 30W):

```
$ upower --show-info /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0         
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SANYO
  model:                45N1779
  [...]
  battery
    [...]
    energy-full:         97.36 Wh
    energy-full-design:  99.47 Wh
    energy-rate:         24.508 W
    [...]
```

Powertop does not show anything suspicious: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okOCv.png)

In Powertop's tab "Tunables" I see "Good" for every item listed.

cpu-info shows "powersave" for all cores.

I boot with:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=Linux nmi_watchdog=0 i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 i915.i915_enable_fbc=1"
```

Any ideas how I could save battery?

**UPDATE 2018-03-02**

Disabling some cores does not reduce the power consumption:

```
for i in {2..7}; do echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$i/online; done
```

According to powertop CPUs are in state "C7s-HSW" > 90% of the time.

Running the following command did not make any difference (suggested by Doug Smythies):

```
for p in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpuidle/state0/disable; do echo 1 | sudo tee $p; done
```

Comment: Suggest you upgrade to the current kernel, 4.4.0-116-generic. Suggest use of turbostat for insight into processor power and GFX power. As a long shot test, try to disable idle state 0, (as su) `for file in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpuidle/state0/disable; do echo "1" > $file; done`

Comment: @DougSmythies Thank you for your suggestions! Turbostat: Busy% < 0.5%, CPU%c1 around 0.5% (except from core0 around 3%), CPU%c3 < 0.3%, CPU%c6 < 0.1%, CPU%c7 > 95%, CoreTmp around 60°C, GFX%rc6 around 98%, GFXMHz 200, PkgWatt around 6.8W, CorWatt 0.1W, GFXWatt 0.01W; cpu*/cpuidle/state0/disable=1 did not make any difference

Comment: O.K. so your excessive power consumption does not appear to be from the processor or graphics (at least any graphics that turbostat knows about). Processor power is a little high, but my experience is with servers (where "idle" can be really quite idle) and not desktops (where "idle" really isn't at all).